# Why did Marv tell Bob that Deeds killed Whelan?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-drop

In one conversation in *The Drop*, Marv tells Bob that Deeds was the one who killed Whelan.
Isn't this strange, given that as I understand it, Bob killed Whelan based on Marv's order? Or am I wrong?

Why would Marv tell him something like that if that was the case?

Answer (score -4):

It is a joke.

I think he meant it in jest like "oh yeah, did you hear, apparently *he* killed Richie Whelan"

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  I'm not sure your answer isn't less clear than the question.  You might improve this by quoting the actual lines from the movie and clarifying who "he" is in each case.

Comment: But it _does_ provide an answer ... the answer proposed is that it was a joke.  It may be short, it may even be incorrect, but it is an answer.